# Why does Laravel ship with Vue? (SPA vs MVC)

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, vue.js, single-page-application

I am a little confused as to why the Laravel framework ships with Vue.js.

My understanding is that Laravel is a traditional MVC framework, while Vue would be used for a SPA; these are both different application architectures, so how can they be used together?

I am currently trying to figure out whether my app is more suited to the traditional vs SPA styles of development and this is something that I am struggling to get my head around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a SPA with an MVC is a common approach as it allows full server side logic to be expressed in the app, and a responsive, application-like user interface on the front end. Often, that involves using the MVC stack to manage the DB and generate JSON responses, while letting the entire UI live in the SPA.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought this might be the case. As an extension to my question, if we are only using laravel to manage the DB and generate JSON, should we not be using something lighter, like lumen? Laravel seems very heavy for something that would only be creating an API.

Comment: That's harder to answer without knowing specifics about your team and experience and what you need for the whole app. If you feel a lighter weight approach would be warranted, then that makes sense, if you are more comfortable in Laravel, then it will probably be fine. Too much for a comment thread though lol

Comment: That's a fair answer. I guess I'll just have to experiment :)

Comment: Why lumen? Today you thing SPA, tomorrow you would need some Admin Panel to the same app, and what? Will you go doing SPA for  admins?

Answer (score 4):

Generally Vue is not used for SPA only.
An MVC architecture relies on tight communication between client and server. Whenever you need new data or need to change data, in an MVC architecture you basically need to reload the whole HTML page which will get you the new updated content.

In order to keep things more interactive and user friendly, some people prefer to deliver initial content by using the MVC architecture which will basically render you the HTML page with some data. After that a javascript library is used to prevent the page from reloading every time you want to change something.

Answer (score 3):

MVC and SPA are not opposite. A single page application has to use an API endpoint, which can (and usually is) be written in MVC - note that a "view" is not necessarily a HTML document, it can be anything that represents the data handled by the application, like JSON.

Comment: That's a very good point! I never thought about JSON actually being the view layer rather than the whole HTML document